# tags: PADS and mentor-pads: same tag, not linked

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I've just noticed that [pads](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pads)

> PADS is a CAD PCB editor produced by Mentor Graphics

and [mentor-pads](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mentor-pads)

> PADS is a software package from Mentor Graphics used for schematic capture, PCB layout, and circuit simulation.

exist and aren't aliasies of each other.

Since [pads](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pads) is **highly** ambiguous, but still has only 68 questions to date, I'd like to replace it with [mentor-pads](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mentor-pads) on all the question about Mentor PADS, and with [pad](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pad) on all question about a PCB contact in SMT technology (and fix the [pad](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pad) description).

Afterwards, I'd like to ask for [pads](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pads) to be blacklisted – with [pad](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pad) and [mentor-pads](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mentor-pads) as the things an asker would immediately recognize as correct tags while typing.

Is that a desirable mode of operation?

Comment: This probably needs a concerted effort by the community to retag questions that currently have the [pads] tag first. Then the [pads] tag can be blacklisted, as appropriate.

Comment: @V2Blast The [pads] tag has been removed from all questions now. Can we blacklist it now?

Comment: @Null: A mod should add the [status-review] tag to this post, if there is community consensus that the tag should be blocked... Though the answers here only have 1 and 2 upvotes respectively, so I'm not sure that consensus has been clearly established. (To be fair, you posted the 1-upvote answer an hour ago, so barely anyone's had time to see it, much less upvote it.)

Comment: (That said, the [pads] tag may not necessarily need to be blocked if no one ends up recreating it; it's possible that the existence of the two other tags with clear tag wikis will be sufficient to keep anyone with 300+ rep (who has the privilege to create tags) from feeling like they need to recreate an ambiguous [pads] tag.)

Comment: @V2Blast I do think [pads] needs to be blocked, as it is too similar to a different concept. Clear tag wikis are the bare minimum but typically are woefully insufficient to encourage users to use tags properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across this same situation and found this discussion, so for the past few days I've been retagging questions using [pads](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pads). This is now complete so we can block [pads](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pads) now.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds good to me.  I am a bit worried about how the tag would be found by people that didn't use the word "mentor"

Comment: typing in "pads" should still suggest it, right?

Comment: Yes, the autosuggest does come up correctly.