# Blacklist [pads]

Tags: discussion, tag-blacklist-request

after [tags: PADS and mentor-pads: same tag, not linked](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8542/tags-pads-and-mentor-pads-same-tag-not-linked/9608#9608) is done, we should now blacklist [pads](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pads).

Answer (score -1):

The CM's have been recently opposed to destroying tags, we usually merge them now with something else. The last few times we have asked, they have suggested merging is a better option, this is a new change.

And moderators cannot delete tags we have to have a CM do that.

Comment: In this case it still makes sense to blacklist the the since it is ambiguous whether you'd merge "pads" with "pad" (for PCB pads) or "mentor-pads". Users are likely to use it the wrong way whichever one you merge it with so it's better to blacklist it.

Comment: Or create a tag called pcb-pads